# Remove last span from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this string:

```
"<span class='break'><div class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon 
 Williamson - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-
 contents'>- wrong</div></span><span class='break'><div class='name-and-
 date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div>
 </strong><div class='note-contents'>- Wrong again</div></span><span 
 class='break'><div class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson 
 - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-contents'>- 
 okay what is the matter with you.</div></span><span class='break'><div 
 class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson - Dec 18,  1:50 PM 
 Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-contents'>- Bro!</div></span>"
```

How can I remove the last span from this string so that I get this return value:

```
"<span class='break'><div class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon 
 Williamson - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-
 contents'>- wrong</div></span><span class='break'><div class='name-and-
 date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div>
 </strong><div class='note-contents'>- Wrong again</div></span><span 
 class='break'><div class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson 
 - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-contents'>- 
 okay what is the matter with you.</div></span>"
```

I understand that it is better practice to use Nokogiri for html parsing but for my use case it's important that I keep the integrity of the string in place. Which means it has to be the exact same except that last span removed.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
string.scan(/<span class='break'>/)
```

But that doesn't grab the entire string and break them into array elements.

#### NOTE: I asked a similar question earlier and I appreciate the help but it wasn't quite what I needed.

Comment: Regular expressions are the wrong tool for this. Use Nokogiri or another HTML parser.

Comment: As I stated in my question. I understand that notion, and I'm not arguing the fact. But for my use case, I really need the string to not be touched or manipulated in any way. It needs to stay exactly the same because I compare it in the next function call.

Comment: In that case, you should consider comparing the parsed/normalized versions, not the raw strings.

Comment: I don't have tons of experience with this particular problem. Why is it bad practice to use raw strings? Could you point me to any articles or stackoverflow discussions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps. Is this what you're looking for?

```
txt = "<span class='break'><div class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon 
 Williamson - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-
 contents'>- wrong</div></span><span class='break'><div class='name-and-
 date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div>
 </strong><div class='note-contents'>- Wrong again</div></span><span 
 class='break'><div class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson 
 - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-contents'>- 
 okay what is the matter with you.</div></span><span class='break'><div 
 class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson - Dec 18,  1:50 PM 
 Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-contents'>- Bro!</div></span>"

txt.rindex('<span')
# => 540 
txt.rindex('</span')
# => 700 
txt[txt.rindex('<span'), txt.rindex('</span')]
# => "<span class='break'><div \n class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson - Dec 18,  1:50 PM \n Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-contents'>- Bro!</div></span>" 
txt[txt.rindex('<span'), txt.rindex('</span')] = ""
txt
# => "<span class='break'><div class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon \n Williamson - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-\n contents'>- wrong</div></span><span class='break'><div class='name-and-\n date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div>\n </strong><div class='note-contents'>- Wrong again</div></span><span \n class='break'><div class='name-and-date'><strong>Mr. Talon Williamson \n - Dec 18,  1:47 PM Eastern</div></strong><div class='note-contents'>- \n okay what is the matter with you.</div></span>"
```

Comment: It is not hardcoding. It uses the numbers given by the `rindex` used right above. I edited the code to make that point clear.

Comment: This is actually close to the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in many ways.

suppose you have that string in txt variable then
`txt.split("<span class='break'")[0..-2].join("<span class='break")`
will easily work. It is only matter of way.

Answer (score 0):

The following would work unless there could be nested `span`s having a class `"break"`.

```
input.scan(%r|<span\s+class=['"]break["']>.*?</span>|m)[0...-1].join
```

Slightly slower, but always works as intended:

```
input[%r|.*(?=<span\s+class=['"]break["']>.*?</span>\z)|m]
```

The latter solution uses [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to catch everything save for the last pattern immediately followed by the string end (`\z`.)

More info on [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), with a regular expression as an argument.